# How to load only current and future events in a dropdown menu and remove old

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering, if it is possible to dynamically add only current and future events in a dropdown menu, and not load the older events. On our current forms, we have to manually remove the events from script and that is not an efficient way.

Thanks, any pointers would be appreciated.

```
<select name="Event" Height="18px" Width="187px">
                  <option value="" selected>Select One</option>
                  <option value="Charles Hall Committee Meeting">Charles Hall Committee Meeting- July 7 2013</option>
 <option value="Townhall Meeting">Townhall Meeting-September 12 2013</option>
</select>
```

These events need to be displayed in a dropdown and should not display if the date is over

Comment: Could you please post your dropdown list code? It will help see what you are currently doing and how to modify/fix it to compare dates.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a server-side task?

Comment: As @JasonP states, this should ***really*** be a server-side activity. After all, what's the point in needlessly sending data to the browser only to then consume more resources removing that data client-side.

Comment: I wasn't so sure about this either, but can I add date to these events?

Comment: so basically it is about adding events as per dates, that is not over yet and display in drop down. preferably browser side.

Comment: Please add the code for your dropdown so people can see what you're working with, and can help you from there.

Comment: What are you doing with the information after the user selects it? Writing it to a file? A database? This could be done pretty easily if the options can be pulled from a database.

Comment: It gets written as a flat file, that is why I don't know how to achieve this, and preference is to not do server side coding.

Comment: thats a really bad preference and bad coding. You could create a php file that has an array that contains all the events. Then include the file on the page you need the array for. Then use a loop to select only relevant dates based on the current date. Assuming you do not want to use a DB for your data of course

Comment: You should really make use of a Javascript MVC framework.

Comment: @suvi: can you please show me an example using MVC, where I can compare dates of these events in arrays and display accordingly in a div?

Comment: @alice provided an example with a description in the answer, hope that helps you out..

Comment: Much appreciate it, I am reading about MVC and looks like a much better approach. Thanks again.

Comment: Good to hear, especially if your app has more components that are connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I previously mentioned an MVC framework would be a good option. Choosing the right MVC framework though - you have many options there. You can even just do this with pure Javascript, or even jQuery - but MVC's will eventually make your life easier. The example I've provided below uses AngularJS (which is pretty heavy, maybe too heavy for your intended use but once you start working your way through Angular it makes your life **super** easy).

I won't make this answer a tutorial on AngularJS but I'd recommend you going through tutorials and documentation on it from a variety of resources you can find online (starting with [Angular's site](http://angularjs.org/) itself). Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/LAZX6/) showing an example of how to use angular to dynamically populate your options for a `select` dropdown - which you can follow.

First, I'm assuming the events is an array of objects with `name` and `date` attributes. Then using angular's `select` directive, we can display these items as options by setting up the `ngOptions` ([documented here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect)). The snippet below will populate `<option>` elements with the `name` property of all your events.

```
<select ng-model="event" ng-options="e.name for e in events">
  <option value="">Select Event</option>
</select>
```

Now we want to make it so events that have passed do not show up. The "angular" magic that handles this happens in the custom `filter` you create for the `app` ([tutorial on custom filters](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters)).

```
app.filter('checkDates', function() {
  return function(event) {    
    var filterEvent = [];
    for (var i = 0, length = event.length; i < length; i++){
      if (event[i].date.getTime() >= Date.now()) filterEvent.push(event[i]);
    }
    return filterEvent;
  };
});
```

This will filter out the array of objects being used in your model based on the logic you code. For this case, all events that are greater than today's date are added to a new array which is returned in the filter.

You then use the filter `checkDates` on the model you want filtered. So in `ng-options` define the filter you'll use (once you start using angularjs more you'll come to realize where else you can apply a filter).

```
<select ng-model="event" ng-options="e.name for e in events | checkDates">
  <option value="">Select Event</option>
</select>
```

Couple of resources on filters: [what is a filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter), [using filters in angularjs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.using_filters).

Again, I highly recommend you look into external resources for AngularJS as well. And as mentioned before this is just one example of one MVC framework out there for this problem, there are definitely more options out there - but choosing an MVC framework really comes down to personal preference and I just like the power that AngularJS offers.